# Disabled phone and no computer

Tags: iphone

My phone says it I disabled and I should connect to itunes.  I have no idea what to do and all the answers here require a computer..  Can you help?

Comment: itunes only runs on a computer so that will be the only possible answer. WHat is the exact error message - a screenshot might help

Answer (score 1):

If it is not a temporary disable ( due to incorrect passcode attempts), and is permanent, there's nothing you can do except restoring it from a backup or resetting it.

[This help article](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT204306) clearly says that iTunes is required (either on a Mac or on a PC) to do so whether it is a friend's or apple store's.

The current data cannot be backed up but if you have a cloud backup, it can be used to restore it.